# Is it expected behavior for Chrome and Edge to stop calculations of <span> containers if another tag is embedded?

Tags: html, google-chrome, height

I am seeing an odd issue on chrome calculating the height of a span that I finally narrowed down to an embedded <hr> tag in my <span> container (other tags like DIV have similar results).
Below code exposes this issue. Try the test with and without the embedded <hr> tag and you will see the height calculation fails with the <hr> tag. In fact it only gives the height up to the <hr> tag. So if you move the  <hr> tag after some of the LINEn strings, those lines before the tag will be included in the calculation.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue or does someone have an explanation why it fails on Chrome and Edge? Or possibly an error in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){
    dh = $("div").height();
    sh = $("#forum_tile_span").height();
    forum_tile_span_offsetHeight = document.getElementById("forum_tile_span").offsetHeight;
    alert("dh: " + dh + " sh!: " + sh + " forum_tile_span_offsetHeight!: " + forum_tile_span_offsetHeight);
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
   Press the button to get the size of the span tag. <br>
   1. Test WITHOUT &lt;hr&gt; tag at beginning of span container. <br>
      RESULTS: Correct height on both Firefox & Chrome <br>
   2. Test WITH &lt;hr&gt; tag at beginning of span container. <br>
      RESULTS: Correct height on Firefox, but FAILS on Chrome <br>
       <br>
      Conclusion: It appears Chrome and Edge have issue calculating height of span if an &lt;HR&gt; tag is included. <br>


</p>
<div class="forum_tile" style="font-size: 50px;height:100px;width:300px;padding:10px;margin:3px;border:1px solid blue;background-color:lightblue;">
<span id="forum_tile_span">
<!-- Place <hr> tag here for test#2 -->
<hr> 
LINE1
LINE2
LINE3
LINE4
</span>
</div><br>

<button>Display the height of span</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I found that using .getBoundingClientRect().height instead of .height() or .offsetHeight will provide an actual value and not fail.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing out that function, but unfortunately, it does not give the height of the content when text is overflowing. You can see in this example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_getboundingclientrect   ...if you add CSS font-size: 30px; to their DIV id="myDiv", it does not affect the height and width returned.